# Bulk update of specific columns (not all) in a table using python list of dictionaries

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

I would like to perform bulk_update_mappings on a table using a python list of dictionaries that has selective columns as keys and its values.

Here is the table class and the python list of dict.

```
class KpcComputation(BASE):
    """KpcComputation model class"""
    __tablename__ = 'kpc_computation_v2'
    __table_args__ = {'useexisting': True}

    kc_rs_id = Column('kc_rs_id', Integer, ForeignKey("review_sentences_v2.rs_id"))
    kc_kpc_id = Column('kc_kpc_id', Integer, ForeignKey("kpc_v2.kpc_id"))
    kc_kpc_score = Column('kc_kpc_score', Float)
    kc_sentiment = Column('kc_sentiment', String)
    kc_sentiment_score = Column('kc_sentiment_score', Float)
    kc_last_updated_date_time = Column(
        DateTime,
        onupdate=datetime.datetime.now,
        default=datetime.datetime.now
    )
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'primary_key': [kc_rs_id, kc_kpc_id]}

dict_data = [{'kc_rs_id': 1194773, 'kc_sentiment': 'neutral', 'kc_sentiment_score': 2.0},
             {'kc_rs_id': 1194774, 'kc_sentiment': 'positive', 'kc_sentiment_score': 3.0},
             {'kc_rs_id': 1550643, 'kc_sentiment': 'negative', 'kc_sentiment_score': 1.0}]
```

The update operation has to happen only on kc_sentiment and kc_sentiment_score wherever the kc_rs_id matches between the table and the python list of dict. I tried the following method to update,

```
self.session.bulk_update_mappings(KpcComputation, dict_data)
self.session.commit()
```

My understanding is that the above statement will update the rows with new values wherever the kc_rs_id matches. But I feel I'm missing something.

I have tried finding ways to perform bulk update on specific columns but some answers suggested to use values for all the columns (filling columns that are not of insterest with some default values) which is not what I want. I'm new to SQLAlchemy so not able figure out how to exactly achieve this. Are there any better ways to do the same? Any suggestion is appreciated.